# How to get karma javascript junit xml reports into sonar

Tags: junit, sonarqube, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, sonar-runner

Is there a karma reporter which can be used to generate a `results.xml` file which is compatible with the sonar Generic Test Coverage plugin? Or alternatively a parser for the junit file which is output by `karma-junit-reporter` and which will work with the generic plugin?

I am using SonarQube 5.3 and Karma / Jasmine

I want to import the junit reports that come from karma into SonarQube but cannot see a way to do this easily. Something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-sonar-generic-test-coverage for karma

FYI I have seen 
`karma-junit-sonarqube-reporter` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-junit-sonarqube-reporter) but that seems to expect the name of the test to match the path to the file which is too restrictive for me. 
`karma-sonarqube-unit-reporter` seems to be unfinished
`grunt-karma-sonar` seems to rely on `jstestdriver` which is deprecated

Answer (score 6):

I managed to achieve this by doing the following.

To get javascript junit reports into sonar

1. find and download `sonar-karma-test-report-plugin-1.0.0.4.jar` which is not available via the update center
2. put jar file in  `/usr/local/Cellar/sonar/5.3/libexec/extensions/plugins` and restart sonar
3. Tell karma to omit the name of the browser

   ```
   junitReporter: {
          useBrowserName: false 
   }
   ```
4. Get Karma to create a junit xml file via the normal karma-junit-reporter and have it call the file `TESTS-xunit.xml` (I had the file called `test-results.xml` and sonar would not detect it WTF)
5. In the `sonar-project.properties` file set `sonar.javascript.karmajstestdriver.reportsPath=reports/js/unit-components/results/`
6. call `sonar-runner`

Sonar requires the path to the test file in order to process the report. Jasmine does not make this available to the reporter. My understanding is the sonar plugin iterates over xml file and finds the classname for each test which has the test name (ie `my cool tests`) and does a string replace to change that to the location of the file